# Sorting elements in a vector by name

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, boolean, polymorphism

```
class Pass{
     string passName;
public:
     friend bool sorted(const Pass &lhs, const Pass &rhs);
}
bool sorted(const Pass &lhs, const Pass &rhs)
{
    return lhs.passName < rhs.passName;
}
class Agent{
     vector <Pass *> listPass;
public:
     void sortPass();
}
void Agent::sortPass()
{
        vector <Pass*>listSort = listPass;
        vector <Pass*>::iterator ptr;
        sort (listSort.begin(), listSort.end(), sorted);
         for(ptr = listSort.begin(); ptr != listSort.end(); ptr++)
            {
            (*ptr)->display();
            }
}
```

What are the possible ways for me to sort the list of Pass by its name? I have implemented the code above but it does not work. I have receive an error of invalid-user defined conversion from 'Pass*' to const Pass&.

Comment: Also you are missing ; after class declaration.

Comment: Generally storing pointers in vector isn't the best practice (unless you are absolutely sure about this), it might cause a memory leak.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `listSort` is vector of pointers, you need to align `sorted` function (and friend declaration) to accept pointers as arguments, like this:

```
bool sorted(const Pass *lhs, const Pass *rhs)
{
    return lhs->passName < rhs->passName;
}
```

and it will work.

friend declaration should look like this:

```
friend bool sorted(const Pass *lhs, const Pass *rhs);
```

Comment: Why do I get an error of base operand '->' has non-pointer type 'const Pass'

Comment: Maybe you haven't updated function parameters, in your original function you are using & which represents references, here I am using * which indicates pointers

Comment: @YeoMengTat if any of answer did work for you you should upvote and mark as answer

Comment: @BartoszPrzybylski It is not **compulsory** to do either.

Answer (score -1):

My preference goes to overloading the operator< so that you will be able to compare 2 pass objects(if you do not need this operator for anything else). By doing this, your call to sort won't need the last argument for comparison, which I find nicer.

```
class Pass{
 string passName;
   public:
 inline bool operator< (const Pass &lhs, const Pass &rhs)){ return( lhs.passName < rhs.passName);}
}

sort (listSort.begin(), listSort.end());
```

As for the rest, the other answers should solve your compilation issues.